# C# Utility to Delete Periodically Aged Files

Tags: c#, open-source, utility

Any recommendation on a C# utility (open source) that can can cleanup/delete  aged files. Ideally runs as a service.

Comment: Why does it have to be a C# service?  There are command-line tools that could be run with the scheduler to get the job done.

Comment: Look at this fresh answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575493/how-to-delete-empty-subfolders-with-powershell>

Comment: because I want to tie to existing applications we have, and monitor using the existing framework we have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a [Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) script that I run as a scheduled task:

```
dir c:\directory-to-watch | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt
    [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-7)} | del
```

Delete all files not touched in the last seven days from c:\directory-to-watch.

Comment: Nice answer, in my experience Powershell  is extremely useful.  I like looks of that commmand.  I should take the time to get more fluent writing ps scripts.

Answer (score 1):

We use xxcopy scripts that we create and that are executed from task scheduler as Forgotten Semicolon mentions above.

Checkout their command line reference.  Their utility is extremely useful and flexible.

http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy01.htm