# Count deleted empty folders

Tags: powershell

I have a script right now that looks for all files certain day old and certain file extension and it deletes all of the files. This works fine and it counts fine

Then I have to delete all folders that correspond to being empty and that includes all sub folders too.
I also have to output this into a file and display each file deleted. The output would show 30 folders deleted but actually 48 were really deleted.

Now my question is i am trying to do a count of all the folders deleted. I have this script but it just counts the deepest folders not all the ones deleted.
Here is the part of the script i can not get to count

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp"
$LogFile = "C:\Summary.txt"
$Count = 0

Date | Out-File -filepath $LogFile

get-childitem $TargetFolder -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.psIsContainer}| sort fullName -des |
Where-Object {!(get-childitem $_.fullName -force)} | ForEach-Object{$Count++; $_.fullName} | remove-item -whatif | Out-File -filepath $LogFile -append

$Count = "Total Folders = " + $Count
$Count | Out-File -filepath $LogFile -append
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the sort call will correctly send each directory through the pipeline in nesting order, since they are not really being removed (`remove-item -whatif`), the parents will still contain their empty child directories and so will not pass the second condition (`!(get-childitem $_.fullName -force)`). Also note that [`Remove-Item`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113373) does not produce any output, so the deleted directories will not appear in the log.

Adapting [Keith Hill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575493/how-to-delete-empty-subfolders-with-powershell/1575580#1575580) to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1575493/2495), here is a modified version of the original script that uses a filter to retrieve all empty directories first, then removes and logs each one:

```
filter Where-Empty {
  $children = @($_ |
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object { -not $_.PSIsContainer })
  if( $_.PSIsContainer -and $children.Length -eq 0 ) {
    $_
  }
}

$emptyDirectories = @(
  Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Recurse -Force |
  Where-Empty |
  Sort-Object -Property FullName -Descending)
$emptyDirectories | ForEach-Object {
  $_ | Remove-Item -WhatIf -Recurse
  $_.FullName | Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append
}

$Count = $emptyDirectories.Count
"Total Folders = $Count" | Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -Append
```

Note that `-Recurse` was added to the call to `Remove-Item`, as empty child directories will remain when using `-WhatIf`. Neither flag should be needed when performing an actual remove on an empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
 get-childitem $TargetFolder -recurse -force |
 where-object{$_.psiscontainer -and -not (get-childitem $_.fullname -recurse -force | where-object {!($_.psiscontainer)}}|
 sort fullName -des |
 Where-Object {!(get-childitem $.fullName -force)} |
 ForEach-Object{$Count++; $_.fullName} |
 remove-item -whatif |
 Out-File -filepath $LogFile -append
```

Comment: That seemed to do the same thing same output occurs