# Option -recurse sometimes does not work for PowerShell cmdlet get-childitem

Tags: powershell

Let's say I have this file:

```
C:\[foo]\bar
```

I then run these PowerShell commands:

```
$path = 'C:\[foo]'
get-childitem -literalpath $path
```

Everything works fine, `get-childitem` shows me the file `bar`, then returns immediately.

Now I add the `-recurse` option:

```
$path = 'C:\[foo]'
get-childitem -literalpath $path -recurse
```

`get-childitem` no longer displays the file `bar`. In addition, the cmdlet runs a long time and displays various "permission denied" error messages for folders underneath `C:\Windows`, apparently because it scans the entire C: drive.

The problem is tied to the fact that the folder `[bar]` has brackets in the name. If I rename the folder to `bar`, i.e. without brackets, the result with recursion works as expected.

My main question: How can I convince `get-childitem` to recursively scan folders that have brackets (or other special characters) in the name?

A secondary question: Is this a known bug?

Environment: Windows 8.1, PowerShell 4.0.

---

EDIT: I verified that in PowerShell 2.0 (on a Windows 7 machine) `get-childitem` returns the same result with or without `-recurse`. It appears that the behaviour has changed either in version 3.0 or 4.0.

Comment: Reported this as a bug, [see here](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedbackdetail/view/1707779/). Please vote if you think this should be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also get the same results as you on Windows 7 x64 bit with PowerShell 4.0. From the looks of it the recursive functionality is ignoring the `-LiteralPath`.

This is a workaround put I found a [TechNet post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0fa34fab-cb35-4369-baad-a320ca610e24/getchilditem-file-recurse-literalpath-ctest-1-does-not-return-any-information?forum=winserverpowershell) discussing the same issue. The OP in that post ended up using `-Path` and double escaping the brackets.

```
$path = "C:\[foo]"
$escapedPath = $path.Replace("[","``[").Replace("]","``]")
Get-ChildItem -Path $escapedPath -Recurse
```

**Note:** This will fail if you remove the `-Recurse`

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\`[foo`]' because it does not exist.
```

Comment: Although ugly as hell, it does the trick. *sigh* One more hack I need to be aware of when using PowerShell :-(

Comment: @herzbube Wait it out. I havent _really_ answered the question yet. Still don't know the real reason for your issue. Someone with more experience than me might know what is going on.

Comment: Yeah, sure, if someone has a better answer I will consider it, but for the moment I am going with your solution. You know, it's a build script that is failing here, so there is some urgency :-)